# Other options of positioning objects in real world without Spatial Mapping; Holo Lens 1 / Mixed Reality Tool Kit

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk, windows-mixed-reality

Hallo I'm currently working for a client on a Holo Lens 1 /Mixed Reality-Application.

My client wants to place the virtual objects firmly on pillars, similar to a museum. Normally I would use spatial mapping and local world anchors to do that.

But the problem is that the holo lens don't recognise the room, because the room and pillars are all very dark or black. And the anchors are connected with the mapping of the room. So that doesn't work.

I know that there is an option of using QR-code to position object relative to the position of this QR-code, but Holo Lens 1 can't capture QR-code (just Holo Lens 2).
Another option would be vuforia but I don't want to use it, because its to expensive for the project.

So now my question: **What other options do I have to place objects without spatial mapping / world anchors, so that they are always on the right position in the room?**

Comment: Light levels is important for the HoloLens to interpret a space. We don’t see other options for HoloLens 1 to ensure anchored holograms stay precisely in place in a very dark environment.

Answer (score -1):

Use Vuforia to recognize a picture then place objects according to this picture.
[[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z4bBMpa4xWo]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z4bBMpa4xWo)